What is the term for changing one or more line/s in a document?
I need to change one or more line/s in a document, as in the following pseudocode.

If document.txt contains:
A


D

Then change line 2 to B and line 3 to C to get:
A
B
C
D


I want to look for a program to do it automatically from a shell script (Bash in my usecase), not manually from a shell text editor like Vim or Nano.
Programs like awk or sed aren't good for me in this case because they are not designed for multilined text processing, but any way multilined text processing is a broad term and may not reflect a specific term I need in this case, hence I ask:
What is the term for changing one or more line/s in a document?
The term I seek is probably not redirecting (>) or appending (>>) but it might be patching.

You are right that patch is the correct tool for this.
Let A:
A


D

and B:
A
B
C
D

then you can run diff A B to obtain AB.diff:
2,3c2,3
< 
< 
---
> B
> C

A diff-file is a sequence of hunks where each hunk start with some line numbering information$^*$, followed by a sequence of "left file" information (prefixed with <), then three dashes --- followed by the "right file" information (prefixed with >).
Given file A and the diff, you can run patch to obtain file B:
[~]$ patch A AB.diff
patching file A

which results in the file
A
B
C
D

You can also check out filterdiff for more advanced ways of obtaining patch sets.
$^*$ In this case, the line number information tells you that lines 2,3 (in the original file) has been changed to yield lines 2,3 in the new file.
